# How many small circles can you put into a bigger circle?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, circles

Is there a formula to calculate the whole number of small circles that can be fitted into a larger circle, and what would the remaining empty space be?

If you would have the maximum number of small circles, how would you place them evenly inside the larger circle?

I do not know how to include the empty spaces in the calculation as their sizes between small circles differ per their placement.

***Example**: Let's say that the larger circle has an inner diameter of 0.2m and the smaller circles have an outer diameter of 0.005m. What is the maximum number of smaller circles that be put inside the bigger circle, and how would ensure even placement across the bigger circle diameter?*

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle)?

Comment: In general, packing is a hard problem. the best known packing of equal circles in a circle $40$ times larger is $1394$. (for a picture, see [this](http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/cci/d117.html)). The best repository of this sort of stuff is probably the [packomania](http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/cci/cci.html) website.

Comment: Interesting. Not seen these before. I wonder what the density tends to as the size of the circles tends to $0$.

Comment: @JamesA Yes, that was the first thing I came by, and it let me to the conclusion that this particular problem is very sophisticated. On top of that, I would like to also ensure that the maximum number of circles can be evenly places such that the centre of gravity in in the centre.

Comment: @achillehui This looks very nice, but extremely hard to solve! Thanks. The calculator (application) is what I was looking for. I was thinking of applying this to a real mechanical problems of small pipes in a heat exchanger, but such high number of tubes may be impossible to put into practice. Do you know whether the solution also considers the centre of gravity?

Comment: @JoshE  Up to my knowledge, the configuration on packomania doesn't consider the "center of gravity".  To pack that many small pipes into an exchange, one possibility is first pack a small of number of them (using a $N$ whose configuration is more or less uniform, eg $N = 37$ or $61$) into bigger pipe and then pack the bigger pipes into exchange.

Comment: @achillehui I think that you are right, based on the packomania description, the centre of gravity lies in a $C_1$ element for almost any solution proposed for large number of inner circles. Yes, I was thinking of arranging as many pipes as possible into a square which fits into a heat exchanger inner diameter, the side of the square is an integer divisible by the outer diameter of the pipes. At the end, the empty spaces on the sides will be evenly filled with pipes (should be relatively easy). The outline of the pipes would then be machined or filled with "something".